# Timed metadata in AAC+ audio-only HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)

Tags: audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, id3, aac+

When producing a live/continous audio-only stream via Apple's HTTP Live Streaming (HLS), is it still possible to utilise timed metadata?

I understand with video you utilise ID3 tags and mux them in to an MPEG-2 transport stream, but I also understand that for audio only a TS is not the right way to go.

What is the correct methodology of including timed metadata in a live continous audio only HLS stream?

Comment: Is there really a problem with streaming ts files with aac audio? I know it's slightly less bandwidth efficient , but you can mux your metadata into the stream as you mentioned.

Comment: Fundamental issue I'm hitting is that Apple's own segmenter app spots audio-only and removes it from the M2TS wrapper and creates simple AAC segments.

Comment: doesn't sound fundamental. there are other segmenters you can try.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of alternative segmenter that might work with this sort of setup?

Comment: ffmpeg supports segmenting for HLS with the -f segment option.

Comment: Unfortunately, however, I don't think it supports splicing the timed id3 metadata in.